# highcharts drill down set data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to change the drill down data in highchart drilldown component. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/
I can change the first screen data with :  `chart10.series[0].setData([9]);` 
but I can't change the data in the second screen- the drill down data. (1,2,3)
any suggest?
thanks a lot !
Mor!

Comment: To be clear, when is it you want to update the data of the drilldown? Is it even when you are viewing something other than the drilldown data?

Comment: Hi @Ondkloss, thanks for responding, i'm adding another link:http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/4/   , if i'm clicking at the king and the queen the data change to "8,9,10" , but I want when i'm clicking on the king to get 8,9,10  and when i'm clicking on the queen to get : 1,1,1

Comment: Aha, okay. Is there any special reason you are using `chart.events.drilldown`? If not, you can use a much easier method, like here: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/5/)

Comment: I want it to be changed dynamically, i'm getting the window.c and window.d from the database, and I want to use setData function to change the drill down data

Comment: I have successfully display the columns with drilldown out with static data. However, I want to change to dynamic data. Could anyone guide me on how to change static data into dynamic data? with my JSFiddleexample

Comment: Oh, I see. Well in your example you would then just have to get your dynamic data and put that into the variable `drilldowns` in `chart.events.drilldown`, since that is the data that is used for your drilldown.

Comment: I just fixed it http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/6/ , but now I have another problem. I want to change the X category lable. it show : king , queen , 2  AND I want it to show me : a,b,c.  any idea?

Comment: `window.c=[['a',8],['b',9],['c',10]];`

Comment: there is another way to add X Axis lables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [highcharts drilldown column chart change Aaxis lables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988891/highcharts-drilldown-column-chart-change-aaxis-lables)