# highcharts drilldown column chart change Aaxis lables

Tags: jquery, highcharts

any idea how to change X Axis lables in the drill down chart? now I get  king , queen , 2 AND I want it to show me : 8,9,10 
I tried to add    `categories: ['9', '8','1'],` but it's not working :\
http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/6/
any idea?
Thanks,
Mor

Comment: Do you want to replace "king" or "queen" or do you want to replace labels over them i.e. "1" and "2"?

Comment: hi , I need to change king , queen, 2 to : 8,9,10

Comment: There are only two columns in your chart with labels "king" and "queen" in the bottom of the bars. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/mnXy3/9/) I replaced the current labels with 9 and 8. ^^

Comment: Hi @Umayr this isn't what I asked for. I don't want to change the king and queen labale ,when I click on the king I get the drill down columns :king , queen , 2 .  I want to change it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second solution is using a pair `{name,y}` where x is category, then on xAxis set type as category. Example:http://jsfiddle.net/mnXy3/11/

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your drilldown data differently

```
window.c = [
        ['9', 8],
        ['8', 9],
        ['1', 10]
    ];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/mnXy3/10/

Comment: That's a mess to read as a comment.  Delete the comment and rather update your question.